# nginx proxy manager how set redirect 443 SSL default to another local web server apache+nginx+LetsEncrypt

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

1. A user from the Internet requests any site whose IP refers to nginx proxy manager
2. If the site name is not found in the nginx proxy manager list, then nginx proxy manager redirects the request
   to another web server with which it is located in the same lock network.

**Client enter brouser site.com -> nginx proxy manager (if not found site) -> Apache+nginx+ssl server**

```
**Apache+nginx+ssl server**
tcp 0 0 192.168.100.37:8080 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 24509/apache2
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 884/mariadbd
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8083 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 954/nginx: master p
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3941/sshd: /usr/sbi
tcp 0 0 192.168.100.37:443 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2324/nginx: master
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:8084 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2324/nginx: master
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:8081 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 24509/apache2
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:9000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 24107/php-fpm: mast
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.53:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 581/systemd-resolve
tcp 0 0 192.168.100.37:8443 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 24509/apache2
tcp 0 0 192.168.100.37:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2324/nginx: master
tcp6 0 0 :::22 :::* LISTEN 3941/sshd: /usr/sbi
udp 0 0 192.168.100.37:68 0.0.0.0:* 579/systemd-network
udp 0 0 127.0.0.53:53 0.0.0.0:* 581/systemd-resolve
```

**I try
/data/nginx/default_host/site.conf WORK ONLY HTTP NEED HTTPS TO**

```
site.conf
# Default Site
# ------------------------------------------------------------
server {
listen 80 default;
listen [::]:80 default;
server_name default-host.localhost;
include conf.d/include/force-ssl.conf
location / {
proxy_pass $scheme://192.168.100.37:80/;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

}
```

Comment: i add

server {
  listen 443 default;
listen [::]:443 default;
  server_name default-host.localhost;
  include conf.d/include/force-ssl.conf;
      location / {
    proxy_pass $scheme://192.168.100.37:443/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}


and have error
Starting nginx ...
app_1  | nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /data/nginx

Comment: Please edit the question rather than try and add config files in comments